# android location with pin on map

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android application which basically shows the real time location of user on map with a pin.

When the user moves the pin should also move. I want to show multiple user's with image and moving pin as location changes on map.

Answer (score 0):

```
    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView); 
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay); 
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation(); 
    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(addfirststandort);
```